# How to Refresh an ODataModel inside an event handler

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am creating a SplitApp. In it, I have set as the default model an OData model through a MockServer that has been previously tested and is working normally.

The currently shown master page has a search field on the header. The search handler is being called and in it I am setting a filter on the List's items binding, but the mocked backend is not being called.

The call to oList.getBinding('items') returns undefined. I have cheched that the binding exists inside the lists mBindingInfos, but the property binding is undefined. There are a template and a factory properties defined though.

How do I trigger the call to the mocked back end having the filter properly applied?

I am using sapui5 version 1.20.7.

Here's a snippet of the view

```xml
<content>
    <List   id="listViagens"
            items="{/ViagemCollection}"
            mode="{device>/listMode}"
            noDataText="Nenhuma viagem encontrada"
            select="onSelect"
            growing="true"
            growingScrollToLoad="true">  
        <items>
            <ObjectListItem
                type="{device>/listItemType}"
                press="onSelect"
                title="{Matricula}">
            </ObjectListItem>
        </items>
    </List>
</content>
```

and here's the event handler

```js
onSearch: function() {
    var aFilters = [];
    var sSearchValue = this.getSearchValue();
    var oList = this.getListaViagens();
    var oFilter;

    if (sSearchValue && sSearchValue.length > 0) {
        oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Matricula", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sSearchValue);
        aFilters.push(oFilter);
    }

    oList.getBinding('items').filter(filters);
},
```

and here is the definition of the sap.m.List getBinding ... it returns undefined because this.mBindingInfos[sName].binding is undefined.

```
function (sName){
    "use strict";
    return this.mBindingInfos[sName] && this.mBindingInfos[sName].binding;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When the binding info is provided but the actual binding is not created, there might be two reasons:

1. The binding info is incomplete or incorrect (e.g. misspelling). You might want to double-check on this.
2. The model isn't propagated to the control and thus, the binding info cannot be resolved into a binding object. You might want to call `oList.getModel()` to check if the model has been propagated to your control.

Another potential mistake, somewhere between the two things mentioned above is the usage of named model (that's when you do `this.setModel(oModel, "myModelName")` somewhere). In that case, you can get the model from a control via e.g. `oList.getModel("myModelName")`. Also, when doing bindings, you need to prefix the binding paths with the model name, e.g. `items="{myModelName>/ViagemCollection}"`.

Last but not least, you should consider upgrading your SAPUI5 runtime. The last released version is around 1.26.x. The version that you are using (1.20.x) is about a year old.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Indeed the oList.getModel() call is failing. I've tried setting the model globally through Core or through the Component. I was under the impression that this would be enough to propagate the models to all controls. Should I manually call setModel on the control or call the appropriate bind method? I thought this wasn't necessary using XML views